# How to handle response on rails with coffescript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form

```
<%= form_tag check_question_path(:id => @question.id), class: "check-form", remote: true do %>
```

The form is been sent to the server and I am tracing the response on my browser but the coffescript is not been triggered.

```
  $(".check-form").on("ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) -> alert("cool"); console.log("success"))
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: You're mixing coffeescript into your plain javascript. It's just not valid javascript, so the browser will never execute it I guess.

Comment: Javascript is valid is there a way to find out if the event is been binded ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the file extension - if it doesn't end in `.coffee` then the CoffeeScript you have there won't get converted to JavaScript before getting sent back to the client, which means it will be invalid, which means the browser won't run it.

A good thing to remember with views in Rails is that the file extensions and their ordering determine how rails will parse something.

For example, if you have a view called:

```
show.html.erb.coffee
```

then from the right-to-left, Rails will process:

1. Any CoffeeScript in the file into JavaScript
2. Any ERB found in the file into HTML
3. Finally, serve the resulting HTML page (i.e. `format.html`)

This would produce, essentially, an HTML page that had some embedded JavaScript in it, assuming there was some JavaScript or CoffeeScript in your view.

If it were, instead:

```
show.html.coffee.erb
```

Then the ERB would be parsed first, then the CoffeeScript, then served as HTML.

This is a contrived example, and may not actually work, but the concept here is that you can stack up multiple parsers in order to combine things where the item after the first dot (in this case `.html`) is the resulting response format type.

So, in your specific example, your file should probably be something like:

```
create.js.coffee
```

So that the CoffeeScript is converted to JavaScript on the server side, then sent as a JavaScript response, which can be executed directly by the client.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have placed your coffeescript code in the $(document).ready callback?

Something like:

```
$(document).ready ()->
   $(".check-form").on("ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) -> alert("cool"); console.log("success"))
```

Additionaly you can add a console.log or an alert to see if this piece of code is being executed when the page loads (**Remember to remove it once you have tested it executes!!**)

```
$(document).ready ()->
   $(".check-form").on("ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) -> alert("cool"); console.log("success"))
   ###
   console.log "This code is executing"
   alert "This code is executing"
   ###
```